# python 3 beautifulsoup не удаётся получить значение элемента с атрибутом name

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
text = ('<offer id="14899" available="true">'
        '<param name="Бренд">Megavent</param>'
        '<manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>'
        '</offer>'
       )
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
brend = soup.find('param', {'name': 'Бренд'})
warranty = soup.find('manufacturer_warranty')
# Найдем элементы
print(brend)
print(warranty)
print('****************')
# Пробуем вывести значение
print(brend.value)
print(warranty.value)
print('****************')
print(brend.text)
print(warranty.text)
print('****************')
print(brend.string)
print(warranty.string)
print('****************')
print(brend.contents)
print(warranty.contents)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так с элементом param?

Comment: а если убрать `, {'name': 'Бренд'}`?

Comment: убрал, результат абсолютно такой же

Comment: выглядит так, как будто tag param имеет какое-то специально значение для BS - достаточно переименовать в para, как все начинает работать. я не знаю почему

Comment: Действительно, меняем название элемента param и работает, спасибо друг!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решается проблема сменой

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
```

на

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml-xml")
```

просто в первом случае текст интерпретируется, как html, а во втором случае, как xml

а тег param имеет вполне определенный формат для html

Comment: Гениально профессор!

Answer (score 1):

Может без супа?

```
from lxml import etree

text = ('<offer id="14899" available="true">'
        '<param name="Бренд">Megavent</param>'
        '<manufacturer_warranty>true</manufacturer_warranty>'
        '</offer>')


root = etree.fromstring(text)

print('root',root.tag)
print('attr',root[0].get('name'))
for el in root:
    print(el.tag,el.text)
```

```
root offer
attr Бренд
param Megavent
manufacturer_warranty true
```

Comment: И это отлично, буду иметь ввиду